# Kinect: How to increment a variable with event handler?

Tags: c#, kinect

I want to want to write an **Initializer** class for `Kinect` sensor. It gathers joints' coordinates for 10o frames (only those where a Skeleton is present) and then calculates average locations.

The code for this has a variable `frame` which is incremented every time a **Skeleton** is found. This code does not work because the `EventHandler` does not seem to increment the variable.

```
Class Initializer
    int frame = 0;

    public Initializer(KinectSensor sensor)
    {
        sensor.SkeletonFrameReady += InitSkeletonEvent;
        sensor.SkeletonStream.Enable();
        Console.WriteLine(done);
        if (frame == 100)
        {
            sensor.SkeletonFrameReady -= InitSkeletonEvent;
            //.. other code
        }
    }

    private void InitSkeletonEvent(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
    {
     ....
     frame += 1;
     .... 
    }
```

Comment: Which part of it does not work? If it does not increment the variable, then the event is probably not being raised.

Comment: if I print out the variable in the eventhandler, it is incremented. But the one in the public Initializer method stays 0.

Comment: Are u sure that `if (frame == 100)` will work?

Comment: Are you sure the code runs on the same thread? Does it help to make the `frame` variable `static`?

Comment: What do you mean by `the one in the public Initializer method`? You don't have any other int variable there, it's defined as your class member so either you didn't show us some important part of the code or you've created another, local frame variable. Don't print, use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

> if I print out the variable in the eventhandler, it is incremented. But the one in the public Initializer method stays 0

This is because `if (frame == 100)` was called immediately after an event subscription, it does not wait until your handler will be called 100 times.

Try to move `if (frame == 100)` to your handler

```
private void InitSkeletonEvent(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
    ....
    frame += 1;
    .... 
    if (frame == 100)
    {
        // assign 'sensor' to the private field in 'Initializer' method
        sensor.SkeletonFrameReady -= InitSkeletonEvent;
        //.. other code
    }
}
```